# How many instances will be there in Spring container?

Tags: spring, singleton, instance

I have a query in Spring, considering default scope as a Singleton into account , if i write xml file like

```
<bean id="singletonscope1" class="com.javabeat.HelloWorld" scope="singleton">
```

```
 <bean id="singletonscope2" class="com.javabeat.HelloWorld" scope="singleton">
```

How many instances will spring container generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generate two separate instances with different bean ids.Within a spring container each bean is identified with its own unique ID.

Comment: I have one concern, if its a singleton it should generate one......in this case values in object will be same or not ??

Comment: Given that you are constructing the beans with same initial values, they will have same values. that said if you change values in one bean it will not reflect in other and the values will differ.